# Python: Linear Programming using Pyscipopt

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, linear-programming

I am optimizing a transportation problem where I want to determine which warehouse to service which customer.

1. Is there a way to set up the constraints so that a customer's demand can only be satisfied by 1 warehouse(not split up and supplied by multiple warehouses)?
2. I ran my model without the above constraint. When I check the results, I found that some warehouse capacity constraints were broken. I know there is more than enough total warehouse capacity for the customer demands.

[Click here to see a screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDhEk.png)

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: I would first tackle point 2. (1) generate an LP file and study it (2) make sure the model is optimal by studying the solver log. Point 1 needs extra binary variables `y(i,j)` indicating if link i->j is used.